# Using earphones with speakers also connected

Tags: audio, speakers

On my new computer, I have speakers plugged into the back of the computer. However when I plug in my earphones into the slot on the side of the base tower, there is no sound!! A few weeks ago they worked fine with the speakers also connected at the back. The earphones only work when I plug them into the slot occupied by the speakers. What do I do to have both working? Is it something to do with nvidia HD audio driver? I might have had this installed before but for some reason I decided to reinstall the exact same drivers and maybe this is why they disappeared?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have two audio cards only one output (speakers or headphones) should work at any given time.  When you plug your headphones in now is there no sound from the headphones and no sound from the speaker or just no sound from the headphones?  If it is the latter then you might want to check your playback devices and make sure headphones are not disabled.